# I'm receiving an error about my robots.txt in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

My website in Google Search Console is reporting an error:

> You have a robots.txt file that we are currently unable to fetch. In
>   such cases we stop crawling your site until we get hold of a
>   robots.txt, or fall back to the last known good robots.txt file. Learn
>   more.

Can someone explain what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

On your website does not have this file **[robots.txt in the root directory](http://trishlaemart.com/robots.txt)**. According to **[Google's help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7424835?hl=en)**: "*Can I place the robots.txt file in a subdirectory?
No. The file must be placed in the topmost directory of the website*". **[Learn about robots.txt files](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en)**.